# Usage of :- (colon dash) in bash

Tags: bash, syntax

What is the meaning of this style in bash?

```
${PUBLIC_INTERFACE:-eth0}
```

What is the purpose of `:-`?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

If `$PUBLIC_INTERFACE` exists and isn't null, return its value, otherwise return `"eth0"`.

There are actually a few of these documented in the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ***${parameter:-word}*** Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
>
> ***${parameter:=word}*** Assign Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then substituted. Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
>
> ***${parameter:?word}*** Display Error if Null or Unset. If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to that effect if word is not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
>
> ***${parameter:+word}*** Use Alternate Value. If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.

Comment: Not just Bash - this is a standard (POSIX) shell feature.

Answer (score 28):

`:-` is used in the `${parameter:-word}` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): if *`parameter`* is null or unset, it expands to the value of *`word`*, otherwise to the value of *`parameter`*.

Example:

```
$ str=
$ echo "${str:-default}"
default
```

This and the similar expansions using `:=`, `:+` and `:?` all come in two flavours: with and without a colon. The difference is that the expansion *with* the colon kicks in for "unset **or null**", whereas *without* the colon, it's just "unset".

Observe:

```
$ str=                      # Null, but not unset
$ echo "${str-default}"     # Expands to value of $str, the empty string
    
$ echo "${str:-default}"    # Expands to "default"
default
```

Where is this useful? A few examples:

- **Default values**

  - The editor invoked to edit the last command with [`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc) is the result of the expansion `${FCEDIT:-${EDITOR:-vi}}`: `$FCEDIT` if defined and not null, or else `$EDITOR` if defined and not null, or else `vi`.
  - A loop in a script that should read from a file if one is provided as an argument and from standard input otherwise could look like this:

    ```sh
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # do something
    done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
    ```
- **When using `set -u`**

  `set -u` is a handy way to force cleaner scripting by having the script die when encountering an unset variable, as promoted by for example [this article](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) (not that I endorse everything in there<sup>1</sup>). If we want to check if a certain variable has a value with `[[ $var ]]`, the script now dies if `var` is unset, even though this might be legitimate.

  The way around this is using `[[ ${var:-} ]]` instead, and `set -u` won't complain. (This is basically using a default value again, but the substituted value is the empty string in this case.<sup>2</sup>)

These expansions are not exclusive to Bash, by the way: the [POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) has them all, too.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> See also [BashFAQ/112, What are the advantages and disadvantages of using `set -u` (or `set -o nounset`)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Just `${var-}` instead of `${var:-}` would actually be sufficient: `set -u` doesn't care about variables that have been set but contain the empty string; only unset ones trigger an error.</sup>

Comment: In the `set -u` workaround, why `[[ ${var:-} ]]` instead of `[[ ${var-} ]]`?

Comment: @wjandrea `var-` would be enough, `set -u` doesn't complain about expansion of a variable that has been set but contains the empty string.