# Please explain these symbols I found in a shell script

Tags: shell

I see the following line in a shell script.

```
CATALINA_BASE=${CATALINA_BASE:-${APP_HOME}/tomcat}
```

Is the `:-` like an `if` statement? That is, if the environment variable `$CATALINA_BASE` exists, use its value for the variable `CATALINA_BASE`?

I also see this line:

```
APP_USER=${APP_USER:?}
```

What does the `?` mean? In this case, there is no `-`.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: ...also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations

Comment: ...also, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of :- in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-in-bash) -- note that accepted answer also covers the `:` case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${foo:-bar}` and `${foo:bar}` are both parameter expansions with defaults. They vary in terms of how they expand an explicitly-set empty string (as opposed to a null, unset string).

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073, or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations for explanations of these and more.