# What does ${MY_VAR:-1} mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I saw this mentioned in [some documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Reliability#heroku). But it doesn't seem to do anything...

```
~ $ echo $DYNO
run.9917
~ $ echo ${DYNO}
run.9917
~ $ echo ${DYNO:-1}
run.9917
```

What does the `:-1` do?

Comment: unfortunately it's closed before i post my answer. here is a good reference for it: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${var:-word}` If `var` is null or unset, `word` is substituted for `var`. The value of `var` does not change.

```
$> echo "${bar:-1}"
$> 1
$> bar=3
$> echo "${bar:-1}"
$> 3
$> echo "${bar-1}"
$> 3
```

Comment: Thanks. Wanna add some examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390406/usage-of-in-bash

Comment: @JohnBachir. In short, `${var:-word}` allows `word` to serve as the **default value** for `var` in case `var` is **(1)** not already set, or **(2)** empty/null. There are other variations that change the circumstances under which `word` is used as the value for `var`.

Answer (score 2):

`${DYNO:-1}` means if `DYNO` exists and isn’t null, return its value; otherwise return `1`.  It's the `:-` between the variable's name and the default value inside the `{}` that make this happen.

Comment: note: `:` optional here. this `${DYNO-1}` work too.

Comment: @Зелёный thanks, didn't know that!  Just tried it out and works fine.

Comment: not for all but for some case  of variable substitution this works. +1 for you.

Comment: @Зелёный that's not all true. `:-` means not defined and not null, while `-` means not defined **only**. have a look http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-32

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Interesting, so we get some new behavior.  And I see that's similarly true for `${var=val}`, `${var+val}` and `${var?message}`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr the colon (`:`) is actually optional. If the colon is ommited, then change "exists and isn't null" to "exists" as i know. Except `${var:offset:length}`

Comment: @Зелёный that's not optional. if you have `VAR=''`, `${VAR:-foo}` will be `foo` while `${VAR-foo}` will remain empty string.

Comment: @PaulEvans exactly. see this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22728.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [Shell Parameter Section of the Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

`"${var:-1}"` means expand the parameter named `var` if it's defined, and if not, expand `1` instead.

Other, similar expansions:

- `"${var: -1}"` means expand the substring of `var` from the last character.
- `"${var:=1}"` means assign `1` to `var` if it's not defined and then, either way, expand the parameter.

Examples:

```
$ x=hi y=
$ echo "${x:-1}" "${x: -1}" "${y:-2}"
hi i 2
```