# Conditional expression in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I want to map volume `$HOME/.local` to either `/home/$USER/.local` or `/root/.local` based on if $USER is root or some nonroot user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose, conditional statements? (e.g. add volume only if condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387076/docker-compose-conditional-statements-e-g-add-volume-only-if-condition)

Comment: Not.  There is no solution satisfying this question there.