# docker compose: use GPU if available, else start container without one

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu

I'm using `docker compose` to run a container:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [ gpu ]
```

The container *can* benefit from the presence of a GPU, but it does not strictly need one. Using the above `docker-compose.yaml` results in an error

> Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

when being used on a machine without a GPU. Is it possible to specify "use a GPU, if one is available, else start the container without one"?

Comment: I found this resource, hoping it can help you:
https://github.com/eywalker/nvidia-docker-compose/issues/1

Comment: @damdamo Thanks for the resource! But if I understand it correctly, it still does not solve the problem since I'm not looking for a way to disable the GPU (then I could just remove the `deploy` section) but I need something adaptive.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

While not being fully automatic, there at least exists an option to disable the GPU, using a [profile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/), so that users can switch off GPU usage without fiddling with the `docker-compose.yaml`, but instead using a CLI flag.

[Here](https://github.com/AbdBarho/stable-diffusion-webui-docker/blob/b5cdf299ca508504f8311df6ab92c07ffe5e04b9/docker-compose.yml#L34) is an example for how to remove the `deploy` section, based on the presence of a CLI parameter. The relevant part is:

```
services:
  ...
  auto-cpu:
    <<: *automatic
    profiles: ["auto-cpu"]
    deploy: {}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@herku, there are no conditional statements in docker compose. In 2018 the feature was out of scope https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5756

Anyway you can check this answer with options how to workaround the problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50393225/3730077

Comment: Seems like this problem is as old as docker compose itself. In this specific case, it would be enought for docker to fail less agressively if a GPU is not available. The linked issue is somewhat helpful, at least it tells me that there does not seem to be any way of using environment variables to do conditionals.