# Docker-compose, conditional statements? (e.g. system dependent driver)

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, conditional-statements, devops

This is related to [Docker-compose, conditional statements? (e.g. add volume only if condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387076/docker-compose-conditional-statements-e-g-add-volume-only-if-condition) question but I prefer to ask a new one because my problem is a bit different:
I have a docker-compose.yml with multiple services and multiple storage.
I'd deploy it locally or on Azure ACI.
I'd like to have only one docker-compose.yml , but Azure ACI needs to specify the storage driver:

```
  mysql-data:
    driver: azure_file
      driver_opts:
        share_name: mysql
        storage_account_name: mystore
```

obviously the driver does not exist locally.
Using a variable for the driver like:

```
  mysql-data:
    driver: ${STORAGE_DRIVER}
      driver_opts:
        share_name: mysql
        storage_account_name: mystore
```

Gives an error because the local overlay2 driver doesn't have share_name nor storage_account_name properties.

How can I achieve my problem and keeping only one docker-compose.yml multi-containers deployement ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found that there is solution for conditional statements in docker compose… The only workaround is tu use some sed / awk modification