# Conditional image usage in dockerfile and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387076/docker-compose-conditional-statements-e-g-add-volume-only-if-condition), but it does not help my case.

I have several `docker-compose.yml` files and `Dockerfiles` which I use to build several images with dependencies between them. However, they mostly have passages like:

(on compose)

```
image: my_registry/image_name:${TAG:-latest}
```

Or:

(on dockerfile)

```
FROM my_registry/image_name:latest
```

This is inconvenient for testing purposes, as my_registry only has production images (tags don't help). People often get caught testing stuff in production because of this.

I'd like if possible, to have a flag, setting or whatever such that when I'm in development environment I could set:

(on compose)

```
image: image_name:local
```

Or:

(on dockerfile)

```
FROM image_name:local
```

And ensure I'm using locally built images with local code instead of production images with code in production branch. Basically, any workaround is valid as long as I'm not maintaining separate files.

Comment: What is different between a "local" and "production" image?  Why?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Local would mean that I've built in my machine with the code as it is on my machine. "production" means it was built on a remote server with the code as is found on the main branch of the repository.

Comment: There is some context and background information missing. Normally you have compose files for dev and prod. As prod have more options and for dev you want to only have one or few images build locally.

Answer (score 1):

For the cases where Compose references an `image:` but you want to use a locally-built version, this is a case where using [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/merge/) can help.  A typical setup here is that the `docker-compose.yml` file has the "production" setup

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  something:
    image: my_registry/image_name:${TAG:-latest}
```

But then in the same directory you put a `docker-compose.override.yml`.  This is checked into source control, but not used as part of the production deploys.  That defines options you'd only use locally; the options are merged with what's in the base Compose file.

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  something:
    build: .
```

This will build an image locally; since the combined container definition also has an `image:` line, it will name the built image `my_registry/image_name:latest` (or another value as specified by `$TAG`).  It won't necessarily push the image to the remote repository, unless you explicitly `docker-compose push` it.

The related point is that you can *name* an image as though it existed in the remote repository, even if it doesn't actually exist there.

```bash
docker build -t my_registry/image_name:nonexistent-tag .
docker tag anything my_registry/nonexistent-image
```

When a Dockerfile has a `FROM` line (or any other time you run or use an image), if an image with the right name is used locally, it's used as-is; Docker doesn't contact a registry unless you explicitly ask it to.

The only real problem with this workflow is that Compose doesn't have a way to declare a "service" that only builds an image but doesn't run anything, or to have one build dependent on another build.  You might have to manually build your base image (not necessarily pushing it) before you build your other local images.

```bash
docker build -t my_registry/base_image ./base-image
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

The other key assumption here is that the images themselves are the same across all environments.  If you need details like host names, pass them using a mechanism like environment variables; don't build them into the images.